# object from tfds.load() gives AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'map'

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset

I'm working on a project and I had to change the way the CIFAR10 dataset is brought into the program. Previously, the dataset was loaded from a GCS link, but I'm trying to do it with my code, getting this kind of data

```
ds = tfds.load('cifar10', split=['train'], shuffle_files=False, data_dir=self._data_dir)

type(ds): <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.DatasetV1Adapter'>
ds: <DatasetV1Adapter shapes: ((?, 32, 32, 3), (?,)), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'map'.
```

As an alternative, I tried this:

```
ds = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()[0]

type(ds): <class 'tuple'>

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'repeat'
```

My code is the following. If I comment the line with *ds.map* the program runs through the next lines, but gives another error later.

```
  def _proc_and_batch(self, ds, batch_size):
      def _process_data(input_ds, input_labels):
        input_ds = input_ds.map(lambda x,y:(tf.cast(x, tf.int32),tf.cast(y, tf.int32))) 
        input_ds.set_shape(self._img_shape)
        return pack(image=input_ds(0), label=tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32))

      ds = ds.map(_process_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
      ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
      return ds
```

The original code is the following:

```
  def _proc_and_batch(self, ds, batch_size):
    def _process_data(x_):
      img_ = tf.cast(x_['image'], tf.int32)
      img_.set_shape(self._img_shape)
      return pack(image=img_, label=tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32))

    ds = ds.map(_process_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds
```

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to correct your first code: `...         input_ds = input_ds.map(lambda x,y:(tf.cast(x, tf.int32),tf.cast(y, tf.int32)))  .... `

Comment: @I'mahdi I think that line should be correct. The problem is more on what input_ds is, and why I am loading that kind of class. I'm a beginner with ML and tensorflow.

Comment: No, In `def _process_data(input_ds, input_labels):...` you have only one image in `input_ds` and you can not apply another `.map` on one image.

Comment: Now I've changed that line into `img_ = tf.cast(input_ds, tf.int32)` and it seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: Exactly, It should be correct, have good time

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, thanks to: **I'mahdi**.

To solve the Error of the question, I changed:

```
input_ds = input_ds.map(lambda x,y:(tf.cast(x, tf.int32),tf.cast(y, tf.int32)))
```

into:

```
img_ = tf.cast(input_ds, tf.int32)
```

And, with other changes to solve more (non-related) errors, the code inside *_process_data* becomes:

```
img_ = tf.cast(input_ds, tf.int32)
reshaped_img = tf.reshape(img_, self._img_shape)
return pack(image=reshaped_img, label=tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32))
```